# What software is available for use with AVRISP and USBASP on ATMega48, 328, 2560?

Tags: software, isp

What software is available for use with AVRISP and USBASP on ATMega328, 2560 for read/write fuse, flash and EEPROM for UNO, Pro Mini and Mega2560 board?

(a fact question not opinion) Which software did you use?

Did it work straight forward (like the software did all the needed 'auto select')?

Does it need human selection for options, etc. on the above 3 boards?

Do I need WinAVR installed before able to use the 'ISP software'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everyone uses either [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) (directly or indirectly, e.g. via the Arduino IDE) or the upload capability in Atmel Studio. I cannot speak for AS, but AVRDUDE does require [options](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html) to tell it which programmer and device to use. WinAVR includes AVRDUDE, but is not strictly required as Win32 downloads are available at the AVRDUDE site.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams mentioned, you should look into [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx). You can use a 3rd party AVR programmer (Arduino w/isp) or one from Atmel. The IDE is awesome and has a lot of features like setting fuse bits.